# shape tweening with animation nodes and sound

Tags: animation-nodes, shape-keys, audio

My ultimate intention is to shape tween different object based on different frequency outputs from a song. IE High notes shape tween objects A, low notes shape tween objects B...and so on. (I am no blender genius) At the moment, I have started with beating hearts.

I managed to get sinusoidal shape tweening using the top 6x nodes seen in the image.
However, relating to the bottom set of nodes, I can't work out how to:
a) extract useful sound values (comparing with online tutorials it seems I can't access some of the sound related nodes)
b) translate them into a useful value to input into shape tween

(I am using blender 2.8RC and a recent animation nodes)
[image: screenshot of objects and initial nodes]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Why are you evaluating a constant falloff? You may just plug the Spectrum output to the shape key value.

Comment: I am totally not sure what you're asking or indeed if it is relevant to my main question. Since shape Keys operate from 0->1 I wanted to make sure I was putting in values that roughly range from 0->1.